# Unable to Install and Use .Net SDK on Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: c#, ubuntu, .net-core

I am unable to properly use / install the C# dotnet sdk.

Here are the steps I have taken:

First I configured the ppa:

```
wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/22.10/packages-microsoft-prod.deb 
sudo dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
```

Then I performed installs for the sdk and runtime:

```
sudo apt install apt-transport-https 
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install dotnet-sdk-6.0 

sudo apt install apt-transport-https 
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install dotnet-runtime-6.0
```

When I test my install using `dotnet --version` I get:

```
The command could not be loaded, possibly because:
  * You intended to execute a .NET application:
      The application '--version' does not exist.
  * You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:
      No .NET SDKs were found.

Download a .NET SDK:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

Learn about SDK resolution:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/sdk-not-found
```

Advise would be very appreciated!

Comment: The following may be helpful: [Install .NET on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux)

Comment: Thanks -- I did try the instructions here, but ended up with the same problem.